# Xcode SwiftUI project compiler error #include <atomic> file not found

Tags: swift, objective-c

I am trying to use a C++ library (Sony Remote SDK) in a macOS project and I have successfully created an Objective-C test project but when I tried to create a SwiftUI version of the same project I get a compiler error (failed to emit precompiled header) complaining that the #include <atomic> file is not found (from one of the C++ header file imported by one of the Objective-C++ wrapper classes that will be called by the Swift code).

What is the explanation for this error and how can I fix this issue for the Swift project ?

The atomic.h appears to be present in the macOS12.1/usr/include/c++/V1 libraries

Comment: Swift cannot import Objective-C++

Comment: So how are you meant to wrap a C++ object if not with an Obj-c++ wrapper than gets imported to Swift ?

Comment: Don't include C++ stuff in the header, put everything C++ in the .mm instead. I think Swift compiler only looks at the headers. If you can't hide it from the header, you can probably "private implementation" it, but I think you should be able to put everything into .mm, just don't put C++ stuff into ivars.